# ran into this issue with gradle when i tried to create a signed bundle

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

i got this after updating the plugin to 8.0.0 and the jdk to 17-
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Cannot convert string value 'UNIFIED_TEST_PLATFORM' to an enum value of type 'com.android.builder.model.AndroidGradlePluginProjectFlags$BooleanFlag' (valid case insensitive values: APPLICATION_R_CLASS_CONSTANT_IDS, TEST_R_CLASS_CONSTANT_IDS, TRANSITIVE_R_CLASS, JETPACK_COMPOSE, ML_MODEL_BINDING)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.addBuildModels(ProjectImportAction.java:258)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:116)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:41)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:64)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.runAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:131)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.fromBuildModel(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:104)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.fromBuildModel(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:84)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.fromBuildModel(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:57)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$fromBuildModel$2(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:81)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$4(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:98)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$6(StateTransitionController.java:177)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:258)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$7(StateTransitionController.java:177)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:177)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:95)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.fromBuildModel(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:73)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.runClientAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:43)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:53)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:65)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:140)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.continuous.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:100)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:88)
at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:63)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:50)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:38)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:64)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert string value 'UNIFIED_TEST_PLATFORM' to an enum value of type 'com.android.builder.model.AndroidGradlePluginProjectFlags$BooleanFlag' (valid case insensitive values: APPLICATION_R_CLASS_CONSTANT_IDS, TEST_R_CLASS_CONSTANT_IDS, TRANSITIVE_R_CLASS, JETPACK_COMPOSE, ML_MODEL_BINDING)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter.toEnum(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:204)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter.adaptToEnum(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:177)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter.createView(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:146)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter.convert(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:276)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter.convertMap(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:284)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter.convert(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:267)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter.access$1500(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:56)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$AdaptingMethodInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:477)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$PropertyCachingMethodInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:705)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$SafeMethodInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:742)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$SupportedPropertyInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:766)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$InvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:432)
at jdk.proxy6/jdk.proxy6.$Proxy155.getBooleanFlagMap(Unknown Source)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ModelCacheKt.modelCacheImpl$androidGradlePluginProjectFlagsFrom(ModelCache.kt:1041)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ModelCacheKt.modelCacheImpl$androidProjectFrom(ModelCache.kt:1075)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ModelCacheKt.access$modelCacheImpl$androidProjectFrom(ModelCache.kt:1)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ModelCacheKt$modelCacheImpl$1.androidProjectFrom(ModelCache.kt:1161)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidExtraModelProviderWorkerKt.createAndroidModule(AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker.kt:615)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidExtraModelProviderWorkerKt.access$createAndroidModule(AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker.kt:1)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker$populateAndroidModels$modules$1$1.invoke(AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker.kt:133)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker$populateAndroidModels$modules$1$1.invoke(AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker.kt:115)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SequentialSyncActionRunner.runAction(SyncActionRunner.kt:61)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SequentialSyncActionRunner.runActions(SyncActionRunner.kt:57)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker.populateAndroidModels(AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker.kt:113)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker.populateBuildModels(AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker.kt:65)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidExtraModelProvider.populateBuildModels(AndroidExtraModelProvider.kt:52)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.addBuildModels(ProjectImportAction.java:246)

i've tried different plugins, and sdk versions, and lastly i tried to update jdk to 17 but nothing i've tried works, but i am a beginner looking things up online for the last two weeks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.